# How to load a 34 MB file by UPDATE into a BLOB-field of a mysql-table

Tags: mysql, blob

When I tried to load the 34 MB file, the following error-messages appeared:

"MySQL server has gone away"

```
2021-09-20 17:01:44 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2021-09-21 21:57:54 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2021-09-21 21:57:54 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2021-09-21 21:57:54 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2021-09-21 21:57:54 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2021-09-21 21:57:54 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2021-09-21 21:57:54 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2021-09-21 21:57:54 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2021-09-21 21:57:55 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery from checkpoint LSN=16069708
2021-09-21 21:57:58 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2021-09-21 21:57:58 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
2021-09-21 21:57:58 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2021-09-21 21:57:58 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2021-09-21 21:57:58 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2021-09-21 21:57:58 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2021-09-21 21:57:58 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2021-09-21 21:57:58 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.20 started; log sequence number 16069717; transaction id 2957
2021-09-21 21:57:58 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2021-09-21 21:57:58 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2021-09-21 21:57:58 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 210921 21:57:58
2021-09-21 21:57:58 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
```

My filesize (34 MB) is larger than the buffer size (16 MB).
All 128 of 128 rollback segments are active.

What can I do to load my file into a BLOB-field?

Comment: My rule of thumb: files go in the file store, data in the database. For you, this means you don't store a file in a blob. You put it in the filestore with a randomly generated name (to avoid clashes) and store the actual name along with the new name in the database.

Comment: This is a terrible idea. Have you considered the impact this is going to have on your DB's performance? For every three rows you store that have BLOBs of this size, you're using a GB of disk space. Also think of backups. Your DB is going to get bogged down to a crawl in s ahort period of time, and then you're going to face the problem of how to get rid of all those giant BLOB fields you have in your DB and store them on disk instead. The solution is not to put them in there in the first place, but to use a strategy such as the one suggested by @TangentiallyPerpendicular.

Comment: I have found a solution, in C:\xampp\mysql\bin\my.ini set: innodb_buffer_pool_size=256M
innodb_lock_wait_timeout=300
max_allowed_packet=256M
Thanks!